# Renaming a file which is already uploaded in php

Tags: php

Is there any way to rename a file which is already uploaded in a directory? I have a file for example named `file.txt` and is already inside the folder `uploads`. In my database, the filename of the file would be file.txt, so I was wondering if I could modify or change its filename even though it is already uploaded. I want it to change to something like `ExampleText.txt`. I've tried renaming the filename before uploading it but what I'm trying to do is to upload it then afterwards i will rename it. So that i can rename it many times. I've also seen some code using `rename()` but I don't have no idea how to work on with it.

Comment: check php documentation first http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: have you tried? please share the code

Comment: Certainly that is possible. You have to implement it.

Comment: If you would have taken 30 seconds to google the question, "rename file with php", you would have solved this. We expect people to try first, not just post a question here for everything...

Comment: `rename("/uploads/files.txt", "/uploads/ExampleText.txt");` Please Google it next time.

Answer (score 1):

function

```
rename($oldname, $newname);
```

example

```
rename("/uploads/file.txt", "/uploads/ExampleText.txt");
```

try lie this in `$oldname` give your where file stored you told you have stored path in db right. pass it in `$old name` .

Happy coding

Comment: Do not encourage people asking questions without first researching

Comment: I agree you but he is trying some thing to do . he told `rename()` also but he does not know how to do it. so i helped him. any way you are also right